# Apache HttpComponents. Get response for CONNECT request

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm using Apache HtppComponents (version - 4.5.2) and I'm trying to request HTTPS page via proxy server.

**EDIT:**

My main problem is that I need to know how to distinguish between failures of proxy server and failures of requested URIs (for both HTTP and HTTPS). I have a lot of proxies and they are not reliable 100%, so in case of proxy failure I need to retry request with different proxy server.

For example (in case of HTTPS), `NoHttpResponseException` can be returned in both cases, i.e. when proxy failed or when target URL failed. How I can know the root of problem? From where came that `NoHttpResponseException`? From proxy of from target URI?

I thought I can try to read response for `CONNECT`  request to proxy server, and if it is 200, then I it's means that proxy is good and next `NoHttpResponseException` is come from target URL. But if I get `NoHttpResponseException` immediately (before proxy returned me 200 status code for CONNECT), that means that problem with proxy itself, and I need to retry request with different proxy server. But I couldn't find any docs how to get access to response of `CONNECT` request returned by proxy server.

Also, sometimes I'm getting `HttpHostConnectException` and `ConnectTimeoutException`. I'm treating this exceptions as problem with proxy (for both HTTP and HTTPS) - is it right way? Or this 2 exceptions can occur even for target URL?

Comment: Why do you want to have access to CONNECT response message in the first place?

Comment: @oleg Oleg, The root of my problem is that I need to know how to distinguish between failures of proxy server and  failures of requested URIs. For example, `NoHttpResponseException` can be returned in both cases. So I want to read some headers returned by proxy in reposnse of CONNECT request (if there some headers - it's mean proxy is good and problem with destination URI, if there no headers from proxy server - it means `NoHttpResponseException` happened during connecting to proxy)

Comment: @oleg if you have any other suggestions on how to distinguish failures of proxy server and failures of requested URIs (especially related to `NoHttpResponseException `), please help me with them. Thanks

Comment: By the failure of the proxy do you mean that proxy server is not able to handle any requests or just a particular one. If its the first one then you can host a simple page in your proxy server and try to retrieve that when the any failure occurs, if the simple page can not be retrieved then proxy is down. Other than that you can try to host more than one proxy servers with the same configuration, if both of them fail then most likely the remote server (not the proxy) has failed.

Comment: I' a bit edited my question, now it should be easier to understand what I want

Comment: @11thdimension proxies are not under my control, I can't change them. And each proxy located on different physical machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not going to be pretty but it should do the trick

```
HttpHost myproxy = new HttpHost("myproxy", 8080)
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setProxy(myproxy)
        .setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy() {

            @Override
            public boolean isAuthenticationRequested(HttpHost authhost, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {

                if (myproxy.equals(authhost)) {
                    context.setAttribute("proxy.status", response.getStatusLine());
                }
                return super.isAuthenticationRequested(authhost, response, context);
            }
        })
        .build();

HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://httpbin.org/");
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(get, context)) {
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}
StatusLine proxyStatus = context.getAttribute("proxy.status", StatusLine.class);
System.out.println("Proxy said " + proxyStatus);
```

PS: `HttpHostConnectException` and `ConnectTimeoutException` exceptions can only be thrown on the first hop, that is, when connecting to the proxy. If the proxy fails to connect to the target server for whatever reason it is likely to respond with a 5xx status in response to the CONNECT method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that should help! And can you please give answer to the last paragraph of my question (about `HttpHostConnectException` and `ConnectTimeoutException`)? I need to know if this exceptions can occur only for proxy server or for both cases.

Comment: Tried this code, but `HttpResponse` object contains information from the requested URI, not from proxy's reply to `CONNECT` request. I.e. it's same as using `response.getStatusLine()` directly. In logs I see that proxy returned this status line:  `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established`, but `context.getAttribute("proxy.status", StatusLine.class)` returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. - I.e. it's response from remote server, not from proxy. To prove it I even tried to get headers instead of status-line - and still it's headers from remote server, not from proxy.

Comment: According to logs I understand that this method is called twice. First time with response from Proxy, 2nd time with actual response from remote server. So `"proxy.status"` is overrides  in 2nd call.

Comment: Which is trivial to fix, isn't it? I updated my code with the most straightforward solution to the issue.

Comment: `authhost` is always proxy server, but response can be either from target URL or proxy. I used guard like this       ` if (context.getAttribute("proxy.response") == null )` {
           //set proxy response
        }`